# Custom views and assets for tenants in a multi-tenant rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, multi-tenant

When using a rails engine, overriding views is as easy as creating new views in the right folder. But when creating a multi-tenant rails app where all tenants reside in the same app (they don't use an engine), how can one override views for tenants.

For example:

App has a `views/static/about_us.haml` file which needs to be customized for each tenant. What's the best way to override this file for each tenant?

Comment: Looking at the name, it sounds like a page that can be completely customized. I'd save tenants' custom page in some rich form after applying some sanity checks to prevent XSS etc; and display it without HTML escaping. Otherwise, e.g. if there are a few well defined tenants, different files/folders for each: `views/tenant1/static/about_us.haml`, `views/tenant2/static/about_us.haml`.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) which is nice for managing multi tenant environments. Apartment helps you managing schema-based database and helps you with the migration stuff.

The app uses the right schema depending on the subdomain. For example, in the case of superclient.mysuperapp.com, rails will use the *superclient* database schema and will work only on this schema until the request finishes.

For **multitenant views**, in my case I use a before_action in ApplicationController.rb to **prepend** my custom view path:

```
def prepend_view_paths
  subdomain = request.subdomain
  prepend_view_path "app/views/multitenancy/#{subdomain}"
end
```

Where *subdomain* in this case is superclient.

The logic is this: first, rails will look for a view in this path: "app/views/multitenancy/#{subdomain}". And if it doesn't find anything, it continues to find the view in the other paths on the list.

I hope my response will help you.